# How to add Vim Keybind? (C-M-S-p)

Tags: vim, shortcut, hotkeys

I want to map the `:PrettierAsync` command from the prettier plugin to the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

I have tried the command: `map <C-M-S-p> :PrettierAsync` but that did not work.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I very much doubt such mapping is possible in terminal `vim` — terminals cannot access all possible shift combinations. Actually terminals can access only very limited ones. For GUI `gvim` the mapping `map <M-C-S-P> :PrettierAsync<CR>` works for me; please note `<CR>` at the end.

Comment: If you are using a recent enough version of xterm and a recent enough version of Vim, then see `:help modifyOtherKeys`. If not, you can forget about it. FWIW, Prettier is a code formatter so the canonical way to integarte it with Vim is via `:help gq` and `:help 'formatprg'`.